# manipulate data in array of strings

Tags: go

I have an array of strings:

```
var a [5]string
a[0] = "red|apple|1"
a[1] = "yellow|apple|3"
a[2] = "red|apple|4"
```

I need to convert the data to array or map or whatever but if first and second values between pipes are the same the numbers should be added, so my desired output would be:

```
var b [5]string
a[0] = "red|apple|5"
a[1] = "yellow|apple|3"
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: the only idea was to slice strings, convert it to map and then try to add the values but it involves so many loops that I gave up for a moment, because maybe there is something simpler to implement

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map to achieve that.

```
var a [3]string
a[0] = "red|apple|1"
a[1] = "yellow|apple|3"
a[2] = "red|apple|4"

b := make(map[string]int)

for _, s := range a {
    k := s[:len(s)-2]
    v := s[len(s)-1:]
    i, err:= strconv.Atoi(v) // please, check for errors
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("bad input")
        continue
    }
    b[k] += i
}

for k, v := range b {
    fmt.Println(k, v)
}
```

Output:

```
yellow|apple 3
red|apple 5
```